# I need some flexbox help swapping the order of items between portrait and landscape mode

Tags: html, css, flexbox

This is a wireframe that shows how our page currently looks like in landscape mode and what items are in them.

[landscape wireframe here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDcaf.png)

Here is the code that goes with the first wireframe.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="column">
    <div id="1" class="one"></div>
    <div id="2" class="two"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="3" class="three"></div>
  <div id="4" class="four"></div>
</div>

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

I have tried reordering the items but it seems the column class that one and two are in have them trapped when changing to the portrait layout.

I need to take these divs and change them into a new layout for portrait mode and possibly landscape mode without duplicating any divs. Is there a way to turn the landscape layout into the portrait mode wireframe only using flex? Or is there a way to change the code in the landscape layout to work for both wireframes?

[Here is the portrait wireframe.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6R2V.png)

Answer (score 0):

I believe your best bet in this case is to use the [Grid Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) instead of Flex.

Splitting 1 and 2 in the portrait wireframe seems impossible with Flex without totally messing with the DOM.